# Process and check event using kafka-streams during some period

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream  eventsStream, which is get data from a topic "events". 
There is two type of events, their keys:
1. `{user_id = X, event_id = 1} {..value, include time_event...}`
2. `{user_id = X, event_id = 2} {..value, include time_event...}`

I need to migrate events with `event_id = 1` to a topic "results" if during 10 minutes there is not given an event with `event_id = 2` by user.

For example,
1. First case: we get data  `{user_id = 100, event_id = 1} {.. time_event = xxxx ...}` and no events during 10 minutes `{user_id = 100, event_id = 2} {.. time_event = xxxx + 10 minutes...}`, so we'll write it to results-topic
2. Second case: we get data  `{user_id = 100, event_id = 1} {.. time_event = xxxx ...}` and an event during 10 minutes `{user_id = 100, event_id = 2} {.. time_event = xxxx + 5 minutes...}`, so we'll not write it to results-topic

How does it possible to realise in java code this behavior using kafka-streams?

**My code:**

***public class ResultStream {***

```
public static KafkaStreams newStream() {

    Properties properties = Config.getProperties("ResultStream");

    Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> store =
            Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                    Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("inmemory"),
                    stringSerde,
                    stringSerde
            );
    builder.addStateStore(store);

    KStream<String, String> resourceEventStream = builder.stream(EVENTS.topicName(), Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
    resourceEventStream.print(Printed.toSysOut());

    resourceEventStream.process(() -> new CashProcessor("inmemory"), "inmemory");
    resourceEventStream.process(() -> new FilterProcessor("inmemory", resourceEventStream), "inmemory");

    Topology topology = builder.build();

    return new KafkaStreams(topology, properties);

}
```

***}***

***public class FilterProcessor implements Processor {***

```
private ProcessorContext context;
private String eventStoreName;
private KeyValueStore<String, String> eventStore;
private KStream<String, String> stream;

public FilterProcessor(String eventStoreName, KStream<String, String> stream) {
    this.eventStoreName = eventStoreName;
    this.stream = stream;
}

@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
    this.context = processorContext;
    eventStore = (KeyValueStore) processorContext.getStateStore(eventStoreName);
}

@Override
public void process(Object key, Object value) {

    this.context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(1), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, timestamp -> {

        System.out.println("Scheduler is working");

        stream.filter((k, v) -> {

            JsonObject events = new Gson().fromJson(k, JsonObject.class);
            if (***condition***) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }).to("results");
    });
}

@Override
public void close() {

}
```

***}***

CashProcessor's role only to put events to local store, and delete record with event_id = 1 by user if there is given an event_id = 2 with the same user.

FilterProcess should filter events using local store every minute. But I can't invoke correctly this processing (as I do it in fact)...

I'm really need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you pass `KStream` into your processor? That is not how the DSL works.

As you "connect" your processors via `resourceEventStream.process()` already, your `FilterProcessor#process(key, value)` method will be called for each record in the stream automatically -- however, a `KStream#process()` is a terminal operation and thus does not allow you to send any data downstream. Instead, you might want to use `transform()` (that is basically the same as `process()` plus an output `KStream`).

To actually forward data downstream in your punctuation, you should use `context.forward()` using the `ProcessorContext` that is provided via `init()` method.